# Potential Primefaces Dialog Enter Submit Bug?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have the exact same dialog form setup as the primefaces example below. When I put my cursor in the p:inputText on the below primefaces example and hit enter the window is closed automatically.  On  my example, I've even removed all links/buttons etc and just have a form and an input and it still closes the dialog when hitting enter.  Any way around this?

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dialogForm.jsf

mycode:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui"
    xmlns:dc="http://dc.dreamcatcher.com/facelet-taglib">
<ui:composition template="#{layoutBean.registeredTemplate}">
    <ui:define name="content">
        <h:form id="dreamModifyFrm">
        <p:commandLink  onclick="webSearchDlg.show();" value="open"/>
            <p:dialog header="#{bundle['dreamSearch.HEADER']}"
                      widgetVar="webSearchDlg" modal="true" styleClass="dialog dialog2"
                      draggable="false" resizable="false" showEffect="fade" position="top"
                      hideEffect="fade">
                <p:inputText id="searchText" value="#{dreamSearchBean.searchText}"/>
            </p:dialog>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following `onkeyup` attrubute with a little JavaScript to the `<h:form>` or the `<h:inputText>` element to prevent the default action on enter press.

```
onkeyup="return event.keyCode != 13"
```

The enter key has a keycode of 13, so the above will return `false` when it is pressed and so the element's default action will be blocked.

Comment: Thanks BalusC!  I believe if I do this then I wont be able to hit enter to actually submit the form with the desired button. When I use this code then I can't hit enter for a default submit button.  Is there a way to combine the two approaches?  Basically, just make one button available to the enter key press and nothing else on the form?

Comment: Then just don't use it. Rather arrange the button to be the firstnext button element in the HTML DOM tree as opposed to the input elements.

Comment: so just list the submit button first w/in the form and use css to position it at the bottom of the page?  Thats where we need the button for the user

Comment: No, the button should not be before the input elements. They should be after the input elements. Only the firstnext in the HTML DOM tree will be invoked. So if you have two buttons next to each other at the bottom of the form, then only the first one will be invoked.

Comment: I don't understand how to make it "firstnext button element in the HTML DOM tree".  My app is in a dialog window, so one button is at the upper left corner (one I don't want to submit and has a dialog.hide on the onclick) and the other is at the bottom (the one I want to submit)

Answer (score 4):

My issues was fixed using the below:
There is a "feature" in IE where if you have only a single input element inside a form then hitting enter while focus in in the input element causes the form to submit (regardless of whether you even have a submit button). One way to prevent this is to add a second input element with style="display: none;".

Comment: Great work.  This fixed it for me by adding  <p:inputText id="txtIE7Hack" value="" required="false" style="display:none" rendered="#{includeIE7Resource}"/>

Answer (score 2):

Let me just wrap it up from a 2013 perspective:

When using newer PrimeFaces (3.2+?) versions, you can also use

```
<p:defaultCommand target="search-button" />
```

as described here:

http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=1787

ShowCase link:

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/defaultCommand.jsf

Of course, this tag must be directly underneath the h:form tag, otherwise the tag isn't working.

When not using PrimeFaces, you must have something like

```
<h:inputText style="display: none;" />
```

on the form, as described in the earlier answer by c12.

Both of the above will cause **IE browsers** to behave like FF, Chrome, etc. When not using IE at all, BalusC's solution suffices.

Answer (score -1):

I got the same Problem. I have a From with several Dozens InputTexts and several Buttons. When i pressed 'enter' in a inputText, the first Button was triggered and NOT the submit Button.

The hints above (`onkeyup="return event.keyCode != 13"` and `p:commandButton` with `display:none`) didn't work for me.

My solution was pretty simple and works. Just let your Submit-Button be the first button in your HTML-Code. The correct layout/arrangement of Button can be done via CSS, i.e. `"float: left;"`

Example:

```
<p:commandButton value="Save" ajax="true"   
    icon="ui-icon-disk" 
    update="myTable"
    actionListener="#{myTableBean.save()}" />

<p:commandButton id="previousPeriod" update="myTable"
    icon="ui-icon-triangle-1-w" ajax="true" type="push"
    style="float: left;"
    actionListener="#{myTableBean.scrollPrevious}"
    value="Previous" />
```

After putting my Save-Button before my "Previous"-Button, everything worked fine! After pushing "enter" within a inputText, the Form gets submitted now and the `"float:left"` places the Prev-Button before the Save-Button in the visual Layout.

Comment: It is not a p:commandbutton wiht none you need to add an input field like:   <p:inputText id="txtIE7Hack" value="" required="false" style="display:none" rendered="#{includeIE7Resource}"/>